# Keep getting Array to string conversion notice but cannot see why

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting an array to string conversion notice, it seems to be from the way I have escaped (or haven't escaped) the MySQL statement. If I do not use a PHP variable and put the data in as text it works, but with the variables it shows an error. Help! :)

```
function lastBackupStatus($server,$node){
  $serverstatus = "";
  $i=1;
  $result = mysql_query("select
    max(case when status LIKE '%Failed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Failed,
    max(case when status LIKE '%Missed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Missed,
    max(case when status LIKE '%Completed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Completed,
    node_name,
    schedule_name
    from `events_".$server."`
    where node_name='".$node."'
    group by node_name, schedule_name
    ORDER BY last_failed");
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($count!== 0){
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )){
      if($i < $count){
        $serverstatus .="";//do nothing
      }else{
        if($info['Last_Failed']  > $info['Last_Completed']){
          if($info['Last_Failed'] > $info['Last_Missed']){
            $serverstatus .="Failed:". $info['Last_Failed'].
              $info['node_name'].$info['schedule_name']."</br>";
          }
        }
        if($info['Last_Missed'] > $info['Last_Completed']){
          if ($info['Last_Missed'] > $info['Last_Failed']){
            $serverstatus .=" Missed: ". $info['Last_Failed'].
              $info['node_name'].$info['schedule_name']."</br>";
          }
        }
      }
      $i++;
    }
  } else {
    $serverstatus .= "count is 0";
  }
  return $serverstatus;
}
```

Comment: can you specify the line number on which you are getting the error? or just copy that line and enter on bottom of code

Comment: its line 50 which is where node_name='".$node."'

Comment: specifically this piece of code is causing the error "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\TSM\files\Backups.php on line 50
" the Code:    $result = mysql_query("select 
max(case when status LIKE '%Failed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Failed, 
max(case when status LIKE '%Missed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Missed,
max(case when status LIKE '%Completed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Completed,
node_name,
schedule_name 
from `events_".$server."` 
where node_name='".$node."'
group by node_name, schedule_name 
ORDER BY last_failed");

Comment: Do `var_dump($node)` - what do you get?

Comment: if you are getting error on node_name=".$node."', have you tried var_dumping the $node to see what it holds?

Comment: ah no i didnt try var_dump, and of course that showed exactly what was wrong! lol, thanks guys it was that $node should have been $node['node_name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `AS` keyword:

```
max(case when status LIKE '%Failed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Failed, 
max(case when status LIKE '%Missed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Missed,
max(case when status LIKE '%Completed%' then scheduled_start end) Last_Completed,
```

should be

```
max(case when status LIKE '%Failed%' then scheduled_start end) AS Last_Failed, 
max(case when status LIKE '%Missed%' then scheduled_start end) AS Last_Missed,
max(case when status LIKE '%Completed%' then scheduled_start end) AS Last_Completed,
```

Therefore `$info['Last_Failed']` had no associative index, etc.

Per your comment, it appears `$node` was an array after all, and you need to replace this:

```
where node_name='".$node."'
```

with this:

```
where node_name='".$node['node_name']."'
```

Comment: good point, but for some strange reason that didnt cause an error, if i do not use the $server and $node variables and replace them with words so its one big string, it works fine?

Comment: What do you get if you type `var_dump($node)` at the top of the function?